# Can I partially apply a ControlTemplate in WPF?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I'm pretty green when it comes to WPF, so forgive me if this is an obvious question.

I'm trying to modify an existing code base that is using the Divelements SandRibbon libraries, but am finding that the GalleryButton control doesn't behave quite how I'd like. What I'd like to do is change the way GalleryButton arranges the image and label, but keep the default 'look' for all triggers such as mouse over etc.

Is it possible to apply a ControlTemplate to some parts of a control but not others? I want to specify that the GalleryButton displays its 'Image' and 'Text' properties differently than the defaults, but not touch anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no -- it's all or nothing. However, one solution I've used before is to simply sublass the control and alter the layout in code behind in OnApplyTemplate.

Comment: Thanks for the 'subclassing' tip. I'll give it a go.

Comment: See also `<Style BasedOn="...">`.